# Azure ARM template to register AD Application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

I am trying to automate the azure AD application registration and client secret creation process after that emit these values in output. For that I created a managed identity and then tried to assign a role to that managed identity after that app registration happens.

in that flow following error happens after creating a managed identity.

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/78c50b17-61fd-40cc-819c-4953586c7850/resourceGroups/CloudSpend/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Microsoft.Template-20230705222241","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'identity' on object of type 'DeploymentPropertiesContent'. Path 'properties.identity', line 1, position 95.'."}]}

what change have to be done to achieve this?

Template :::

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {},
 "variables": {
    "applicationName" : "app via arm",
    "managedIdentityName" : "managedidentity_2",
    "powershellScript": "[concat('# PowerShell script to register the application in Azure AD and create a client secret', ';$appName = \"MyApp\";$replyUrl = \"https://myapp.azurewebsites.net\";$app = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName -ReplyUrls @($replyUrl);$clientSecret = New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId -EndDate ([DateTime]::UtcNow.AddYears(2));Write-Output $app.ApplicationId;Write-Output $clientSecret.SecretText;Write-Output \"##vso[task.setvariable variable=appId;]$app.ApplicationId\";Write-Output \"##vso[task.setvariable variable=clientSecret;]$clientSecret.SecretText\";)"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-30",
      "name": "[variables('managedIdentityName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
      "apiVersion": "2022-04-01",
      "name": "[guid(subscription().subscriptionId,resourceGroup().id, variables('managedIdentityName'), 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]",
      "properties": {
      "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c')]",
      "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('managedIdentityName')), '2023-01-31').principalId]",
      //  "scope": "[resourceGroup().id]"
       "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"

      },
      "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('managedIdentityName'))]"]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "registerAppDeployment",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
          "scope": "Inner"
        },
        "identity": {
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
          "[format('{0}', extensionResourceId(format('/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}', subscription().subscriptionId, variables('managedIdentityName')), 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('managedIdentityName')))]": {}
        }
      },
        "template": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "resources": [
            {
              "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
              "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
              "name": "registerAppScript",
              "properties": {
                "AzPowerShellVersion": "3.0",
                "scriptContent": "[variables('powershellScript')]",
                "retentionInterval": "P1D",
                "timeout": "PT1H"
              }
            }
          ],
          "outputs": {
            "appId": {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts', 'registerAppScript')).outputs.appId]"
            },
            "clientSecret": {
              "type": "string",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts', 'registerAppScript')).outputs.clientSecret]"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments', guid(subscription().subscriptionId,resourceGroup().id, variables('managedIdentityName'), 'b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c'))]"]
    }
 
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "identityId": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('managedIdentityName')), '2018-11-30').principalId]"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It could be that freshly created managed identity is not available yet. Could be that if you add a delay at the end of the PowerShell script, it might work.

Comment: Please use Bicep, it's about 5x more readable than JSON and it compiles to ARM anyway 

Comment: is it possible to deploy a bicep file in portal?

Answer (score 0):

The identity

```
"identity": {
        "type": "UserAssigned",
        "userAssignedIdentities": {
          "[format('{0}', extensionResourceId(format('/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}', subscription().subscriptionId, variables('managedIdentityName')), 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities', variables('managedIdentityName')))]": {}
        }
}
```

should be inside `Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts` resource, not on `Microsoft.Resources/deployments`. Moving it into correct scope should fix the issue.

Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/deploymentscripts?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template for more information.

Comment: getting this error while i put identity inside the Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts resource

Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'managedIdentityName' is not found. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-syntax-variables for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)

Comment: You need to set `expressionEvaluationOptions` to `outer`(that is the default)(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#expression-evaluation-scope-in-nested-templates) or pass `powershellScript`and `managedIdentityName` from outer template to inner template and reference parameters. Is there a reason to use nested templates for this use case?